# ReactJS: DOM not scrolling to bottom

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to auto scroll a DOM element to the bottom using React ref system. However, the problem that i have is that the scrollTop attribute remains 0 even though i've set its value to the scrollHeight value.

My code looks like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

class MessageBody extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.msgListRef = React.createRef();
    }

    componentWillUpdate() {
        const node = this.msgListRef.current;
        this.shouldScrollToBottom = node.scrollTop + node.clientHeight + 100 >= node.scrollHeight;
    }

    componentDidUpdate() {
        if (this.shouldScrollToBottom) {
            const node = this.msgListRef.current;
            node.scrollTop = node.scrollHeight;
            console.log('from component update', node, node.scrollHeight, node.scrollTop);
        }
    }

    loadInitialMessageBox(id) {
        axios.post(`/messages/getMessage/${id}`)
            .then(response => {
                let messages = response.data.messages;
                let user = response.data.user;
                // this.state.user = user;
                document.querySelector('.messages-body').innerHTML = `
                        <span class="welcome-text">This is the beginning of your conversation with ${user.name}</span>
                    `;
                document.querySelector('.messages-header-text').textContent = `${user.name}`;
                for (let i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
                    if (messages[i].to == user.slug) {
                        if (i > 0) {
                            if (messages[i].to == messages[i - 1].to) {
                                let div = document.getElementsByClassName('sender-msg');
                                let last_div = div[div.length - 1];
                                last_div.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<div><span title='${messages[i].time}'>${messages[i].text}</span></div>`);
                            } else {
                                let sender_div = document.querySelector('.messages-body');
                                sender_div.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',
                                    `<div class="sender">
                                            <div class="sender-msg">
                                                <div><span title="${messages[i].time}">${messages[i].text}</span></div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>`
                                )
                            }
                        } else {
                            let sender_div = document.querySelector('.messages-body');
                            sender_div.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',
                                `<div class="sender">
                                            <div class="sender-msg">
                                                <div><span title="${messages[i].time}">${messages[i].text}</span></div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>`
                            )
                        }
                    }

                    if (messages[i].from == user.slug) {
                        if (i > 0) {
                            if (messages[i].from == messages[i - 1].from) {
                                let div = document.getElementsByClassName('receiver-msg');
                                let last_div = div[div.length - 1];
                                last_div.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<div><span title='${messages[i].time}'>${messages[i].text}</span></div>`);
                            } else {
                                let msg_div = document.querySelector('.messages-body');
                                msg_div.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',
                                    `<div class="receiver">
                                            <img src="../images/${user.avatar}" alt="User Image">
                                            <div class="receiver-msg">
                                                <div><span title="${messages[i].time}">${messages[i].text}</span></div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>`
                                )
                            }
                        } else {
                            let msg_div = document.querySelector('.messages-body');
                            msg_div.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',
                                `<div class="receiver">
                                            <img src="../images/${user.avatar}" alt="User Image">
                                            <div class="receiver-msg">
                                                <div><span title="${messages[i].time}">${messages[i].text}</span></div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>`
                            )
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="messages-body" ref={this.msgListRef}>
                { this.loadInitialMessageBox(this.props.slug) }
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default MessageBody;
```

Whenever I run the code, I get the following result in the console: `from component update, <div class="messages-body">, 246, 0`. The last result is the scrollTop value which i expected to be 246 but instead it is 0. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to work for me: https://jsfiddle.net/Ltsz6oa1/

My guess is that your `.messages-body` doesn't have a set height and doesn't have the CSS style `overflow: scroll;`. Setting `scrollTop` on an element that can't scroll will leave `scrollTop` at zero, setting it `scrollTop = scrollHeight` will scroll it as far at is can go but it will max out.

Comment: It does have an ```overflow-y: scroll``` and a ```height: 65vh``` in my stylesheet.

Comment: So i looked into the jsfiddle you shared carefully and try to figure out why it works by tweaking your code and then i discovered that the reason why it's working for you is because you added a child div with a set height of 400px. I removed the div and gave the parent div a set height of 2000px but it doesn't work. Therefore, your code is not fully working as you think, it's highly dependent on the height of the child div which you statically set. Try changing the height of the child div to 100px and you will see that it doesn't work also.

Comment: And also if you inspect the page and check the console, you will see that ```node.scrollTop``` is not equal to ```node.scrollHeight```. That's another proof that your code is not actually working, it just seems so.

Comment: "Try changing the height of the child div to 100px" – Yes, that's due to the check `node.scrollTop + node.clientHeight + 100 <= node.scrollHeight`, remove that and it works. "Gave the parent div a set height of 2000px" – Yes, if the parent div is tall, then there is no overflow and therefore no scroll bars. Are you trying to make the window scroll instead of the `.messages-body` element? If so, you need to use `window.scrollTop`. "ScrollTop is not equal to ScrollHeight" – Yes, as I said in my answer ScrollHeight will always be larger than ScrollTop, you can only scroll so far.

Comment: Hmm, I see.....I guess your answer just doesn't work for me. Because i added a new div under ```.messages-body``` with a height of 100px and then removed the check as you said but nothing changed. Can't really figure out where the problem is anymore